# JIT & loop optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, jit

```
using System; 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ 
    class TestMath
    {  
        static void Main()
        {
            double res = 0.0;

            for(int i =0;i<1000000;++i)
                res +=  System.Math.Sqrt(2.0);

            Console.WriteLine(res);

            Console.ReadKey();  
        }
    }
}
```

By benchmarking this code against the c++ version, I discover than performance are 10 times slower than c++ version. I have no problem with that , but that lead me to the following question :

It seems (after a few search) that JIT compiler can't optimize this code as c++ compiler can do, namely just call sqrt once and apply *1000000 on it.

Is there a way to force JIT to do it ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the JIT compiler *can't* do it.  The current version may or may not, but that doesn't mean that a future version won't.  I'm curious- did you try compiling in Release mode, as opposed to Debug mode?  You may find that release mode improves the performance substantially.

Comment: @Chris: yes I have carefully turn release mode on with both language.

Comment: @ChrisShain Are you sure compiler can do this? It must be sure Math.Sqrt doesn't have side effects, so it can reduce it to single call.

Comment: @Euphoric I am sure that a set of rules could be compiled such that any method satisfying those rules could safely be assumed to have no side effects.

Comment: The numbers don't add up for me.  The C# version runs 10 times longer but does a million times the calls?

Comment: Is this code representative of your *actual* code? Given that it's trivial to optimize this in the source code, why wouldn't you do so? If you have more *realistic* code demonstrating a problem, please post it.

Comment: @John: no it's just an educational purpose code. not a production code, if it is what's you mean by "actual".

Comment: In addition to using a release build, also make sure you don't have the debugger attached (i.e. you launch the exe directly outside of visual studio.)

Comment: @Dan: Yes I didn't have the debugger attached when I done my bench

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I repro, I clock the C++ version at 1.2 msec, the C# version at 12.2 msec.  The reason is readily visible if you take a look at the machine code the C++ code generator and optimizer emits.  It rewrites the loop like this (using the C# equivalent):

```
double temp = Math.Sqrt(2.0);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    res += temp;
}
```

That's a combination of two optimizations, called "invariant code motion" and "loop hoisting".  In other words, the C++ compiler knows enough about the sqrt() function to know that its return value is not affected by the surrounding code so can be moved at will.  And that it is then worth-while to move that code outside of the loop and create an extra local variable to store the result.  And that calculating sqrt() is slower than adding.  Sounds obvious but that's a rule that has to built into the optimizer and has to be considered, one of many, many rules.

And yes, the jitter optimizer misses that one.  It is guilty of not being able to spent the same amount of time as the C++ optimizer, it operates under heavy time constraints.  Because if it takes too long then the program takes too much time getting started.

Tongue in cheek: a C# programmer needs to be a bit smarter than the code generator and recognize these optimization opportunities himself.  This is a fairly obvious one.  Well, now that you know about it anyway :)

Comment: Why does the compiler need to know that calculating sqrt is slower than adding? Also, couldn't the C# compiler perform this hoist, rather than leave it to the JIT?

Comment: Well, reason it the other way around.  If sqrt was faster than adding then this would be a bad optimization.  The C# compiler doesn't optimize code, it is a jitter duty.  Same idea as a C++ compiler, it is a code generator duty.

Comment: I must be missing something as I cannot see how you can avoid the N addition operations. What's changing is performing one sqrt instead of N. If N==1 then possibly having the extra register variable is slower, but if we assume N>1 then even if the operation being hoisted was an addition itself, we'd still come out ahead, right?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about.  If you propose turning the repeated addition into a multiplication (possible on paper with res = 1000000 * temp) then, no, that is not a valid optimization.   Floating point math is not associative due to the rounding errors, you'll get a different result.  You can of course write it that way yourself.

Comment: That's not what I was trying to propose. The picture I was trying to paint involved replacing the `sqrt(2.0)` with, say, `1.0+2.0` (an addition operation that has a fixed value). You said it matters that `sqrt` is slower than addition. So if the `sqrt` has the same cost as the addition, what would the compiler do differently? I can't see why your statement about the relative costs makes any difference.

Answer (score 6):

To do the optimization you want, the compiler has to assure that the function **`Sqrt()`** will always return the same value for a certain input.

The compiler can do all kinds of checks that the function isn't using any other "outer" variables to see if it's stateless. But that also doesn't always mean that it can't be affected by side affects.

When a function is called in a loop it should be called in each iteration (think of a multithreaded environment to see why this is important). So usually it's up to the user to take constant stuff out of the loop if he wants that kind of optimization.

Back to the C++ compiler - the compiler might have certain optimization for its library functions. A lot of compilers try to optimize important libraries like the math library, so that might be compiler specific.

Another big difference is in C++ you usually include that kinda stuff from a header file. This means the compiler may have all the information it needs to decide if the function call doesn't change between calls.

The .Net compiler (at compile time - Visual Studio) doesn't always have all the code to parse. Most of the library functions are already compiled (into IL - first stage). And so might not be able to do deep optimizations considering 3rd party dlls. And at the JIT (runtime) compilation it will probably be too costly to do these kind of optimizations across assemblies.

Answer (score 5):

It might help the JIT (or even the C# compiler) if `Math.Sqrt` was annotated as [`[Pure]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx). Then, assuming the arguments to the function are constant as they are in your example, the calculation of the value could be lifted outside the loop.

What's more, such a loop could reasonably be converted into the code:

```
double res = 1000000 * Math.Sqrt(2.0);
```

In theory the compiler or JIT could perform this automatically. However I suspect that it would be optimising for a pattern that happens rarely in actual code.

I opened a [feature request for ReSharper](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336827), suggesting that the design-time tool suggests such a refactoring.